# XAMARIN Error : the deployment failed on the android-sdk

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I tried to launch a new application that I just create with Visual Studio 2019 on the Android Emulator and there is an error message which says that there was an deployment error...

The output of the deboguer gives that :

```
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "com.nathandejoannes.lelab/crc6496aae74069bf02fe.MainActivity"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.nathandejoannes.lelab/crc6496aae74069bf02fe.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Could you show the codes of MainActivity ?

Comment: It's Ok, I solved the problem : I had update something that I mustn't do...